# C++ RNG (Mersenne Twister) needs seed

Tags: c++, random, distribution, seed, mersenne-twister

I have written a RNG class which holds different algorithms, however it does not work as expected. Besides the fact that i want use normal (rather than uniform) distribution my code always returns either the same number (max) or just 2 numbers out of the interval [min,max]:

```
std::function<int(int, int)> mt19937 =
    [](int min, int max) -> int {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
        std::mt19937 engine;
        engine.seed(time(null));
        auto generator = std::bind(distribution, engine);
        return generator();
    };
```

Can anyone explain me what is missing to solve this puzzle? Furthermore, how can i implement normal distribution? Last time i tried out `std::normal_distribution` i was not able to enter bounds!

EDIT: When i speak of a normal distribution i mean that the results of the RNG near the two bounds should not be generated as often as the mean of both. E.g. look at the graphical representation of the standard Gauss distribution. I am referring to it because it visualizes the probabilities of the resulting values which i want to implement/use this way, if you understand.

Comment: You're creating and seeding a new engine every time you want a new number? Maybe you should create the engine and distribution once and then ask them for new numbers as you need them.

Comment: That's not the point. I want to know why this doesn't work!

Comment: That is probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: But it is the point: if you keep reseeding with time(null), which only changes once per second, every time you want a random number then you will keep getting the same answer.

Comment: @Blender: You are right! It works now when i create the engine, the distribution and the seed once and for all! (Gonna edit my question...)

Comment: A RNG uses an algorithm that produces numbers that appear random, but have a a *very* large period of repetition (a highlight of the Mersenne Twister). When you seed, you give the RNG an initial value to start the process with. Each time you ask for another number, it spits out another iteration of the algorithm. Seed once and some problems should be fixed (**edit**: too late :P Didn't refresh page in time).

Comment: @Blender: This is the answer - i will accept it once to submit it as a real answer. Can you create a working lambda-expression for this one? Currently i have no idea (tired and drunk xD) how to implement only one seeding of one engine and one distribution. (However my second wish for "normal distribution" is not yet solved...)

Comment: Create your `engine` outside of the lambda and seed it when you create it. As for the second question, I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: @Blender: My thoughts are these, that i want to control extreme outcomes (min and max and their surroundings) by lowering their probability to be distributed. The result would be, that in the interval [1;100] e.g. the number 50 has a higher prob. to be distributed than maybe the numbers in [90;100].

Comment: @Blender: (Sorry for double post!) Your idea getting the engine out of the lambda-expression is correct. Please answer my question again so i can accept it. Furthermore here is an alogorith which helped me transform my uniform distribution to a normal distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: I've edited my post. I haven't worked with transforming uniform distributions into normal distributions (I've only done to cosine-weighted), but thanks for the link. I'll note it for later, as I'm sure I'll need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal distribution is just this (`x` is a random uniform number):

[image: Normal]

But I see something that could be problematic:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
```

Isn't this giving your number generator an `int` type?

---

To fix the seeding problem, create your engine outside of the lambda and seed it when you create it.

A RNG uses an algorithm that produces numbers that appear random, but have a a very large period of repetition (a highlight of the Mersenne Twister). When you seed, you give the RNG an initial value to start the process with. Each time you ask for another number, it spits out another iteration of the algorithm.

When you seed every iteration:

```
time(NULL)
```

this code changes only every second, so when you request a new random number, it will only change every second.

Comment: Correct. I want this for dice rolls which are not uniform. They should be normal in some parts of my code - therefore i have implemented some different types of algorithms.

Comment: The normal distribution is a *probability* distribution function. All probabilities are strictly smaller than one. If you're using this for dice, then I suggest to get rid of Mersenne twister, as it is made for situations where you request *billions* of random numbers (like a rendering engine, where I use it). Have you tried the default C++ RNG?

Comment: The default with `(s)rand` works like expected but i want that the values distributed like the standard gauss distribution graph looks like, if you understand.

Comment: Don't get offended, but the problem might be with the implementation. You want a normal distribution, but you don't seem to know *what* it is. A PDF (probability distribution function) has a **maximum** of **1** and an integral from `-inf` to `inf` of 1. It describes the probability that a certain range of `x` values have associated with them. What do you want to be in the form of a normal distribution? The outcomes? You have to be more specific, as what you're asking for isn't possible.